# Kronecker's theorem on algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation

> **Theorem (Kronecker):** Let $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ whose all roots in $\mathbb{C}$ have absolute value $1$. Then these roots are some roots of unity.

**Proof:** (1) Let $A=$ companion matrix of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$; it has $n$ distinct roots, so diagonalizable.

(2) Take matrix $U$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with $UAU^{-1}=diag(d_1,\cdots, d_n)$, $d_i$'s are roots of $f(x)$.

(3) As $|D|$ is identity matrix, $|UD^t|=|U|$ for all $t\in\mathbb{N}$.

(4) The subset $\{ A^t=UD^tU^{-1}: t\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is therefore bounded subset of $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$, hence finite.

(5) So $A^l=A^{l+m}$ for some $m>0$. *q.e.d.*

---

**Question:** I didn't understand what is mod of matrix here in (3)? Also in (4), does it considers the set as subset of discrete subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, to conclude that it is finite?

Comment: $|A|$ can be one of many matrix norms. It seems to me that either $\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2=tr(AA^\dagger)$ or $\max_{i,j}\{|a_{ij}|\}$ will work. It also looks like you understood step (4) all right.